# Exception in RichText control

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

Recently I started receiving following exception while using RichText field:

com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Cannot find active content filter named acf

The error goes away when AllPermission grant is added to java.policy.

What can be the reason of this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer (but you can't put images in a comment)

I suggest you take a look at the Active content filtering settings in the xsp.properties file. It might lead you to some answers. see image

[image]